# how to display or get the center/hospital name instead of the hospital/center id

Tags: php

I want to display the center/hospital name instead of h_id in the tblpatient. this is the code that code i used.

```
  $where_clause = "";
  if($_SESSION["type"] == "encoder") $where_clause = " WHERE c.uid = '$uid'";
  $sql="SELECT a.* FROM tblpatient a 
  INNER JOIN tblcenter b ON b.id = a.h_id 
  LEFT JOIN tbluserinfo c ON c.h_id = a.h_id
 
  $where_clause
  ";
```

[output of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v20Hm.png)

[tblpatient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoQEs.png)

[tblcenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqR97.png)

Comment: Well, by choosing to `SELECT` data from the hospital table instead of the patient table.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$where_clause = "";
if ($_SESSION["type"] == "encoder") $where_clause = " WHERE c.uid = '$uid'";
$sql = "
    SELECT a.id, a.fname, a.lname, a.address, a.email, a.mobile, a.symptomps, b.name, a.processed  FROM tblpatient a 
    INNER JOIN tblcenter b ON b.id = a.h_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbluserinfo c ON c.h_id = a.h_id
    $where_clause 
";
```

Basically, you just have to add `b.name` on your select query.

`b.name` means to get the value of `name` column from `b` table (in this case, `b` is your alias of `tblcenter` table)

Comment: @zaidyst there's an error it said that
Warning: Undefined array key "h_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\CCCC\admin\patient\pdisplay.php on line 46

Warning: Undefined array key "h_id" in C:\xampp\htdocs\CCCC\admin\patient\pdisplay.php on line 46 

how to solve this? thank you for your time.

Comment: change this line `SELECT a.id, a.fname, a.lname, a.address, a.email, a.mobile, a.symptomps, b.name, a.processed  FROM tblpatient a` to `SELECT a.*, b.name FROM tblpatient`

Comment: still not working it show this error
Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Unknown table 'trial.a' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CCCC\admin\patient\pdisplay.php:36 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CCCC\admin\patient\pdisplay.php(36): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT a.*, b.n...') #1 

but when I move the asterisk beside the FROM it shows this error
 Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' b.name * FROM tblpatient INNER JOIN tblcenter b ON b.id = a.h_id ...' at line 1 in